# Count the length of repeats in a list in R

Tags: r, count, repeat, find-occurrences

I hope that this question was not asked before, although I carefully checked.

Basically, I have a dataset composed of 21980 rows, and 9 columns. Each rows are composed of 4 values: "other", "anarchy", "stability" and "change". One row being for example:
**1 anarchy anarchy stability anarchy anarchy stability stability other**

**I would like to get a list which would give me for each row (OBJECTID) the length of the repetitions for each government value (anarchy, other, stability, change"**

Illustrate this with former row: 
ID1 other anarchy anarchy anarchy stability stability other stability

The first element of my big output list would be:
      **"anarchy"** = 2, 2 (there are two repeats of length two)
      **"stability"** = 1, 2 (one stability, and a single repeat of length 
      two)
       **other** = 1 (a single other)
        **change** = 0 (no change in this row)

And basically I would like to get this for each row of the whole dataset. The code that I have come up with is the following (unfortunately it does not work):

```
matric
k <- 0

test <- list(rec)
test[[1]]$stability <- 1
test[[1]]$stability <- 2

for (j in 1: length(matric$OBJECTID)) {

  for (i in 2:8) {
    if (matric[j,i] == "stability") (
      while (matric[j,i] == matric[j,i+1]) {
        k <- k+1
        biglist[[j]]$stability <- k
        k <- i+k
      }

    )
      if (matric[j,i] == "change") (
      while (matric[j,i] == matric[j,i+1]) {
        k <- k+1
      biglist[[j]]$change <- k
      k <- i+k
      }
    )

     if (matric[j,i] == "anarchy") (
      while (matric[j,i] == matric[j,i+1]) {
        k <- k+1
        biglist[[j]]$anarchy <- k
      k <- i+k
      }
    )
         if (matric[j,i] == "other") (
      while (matric[j,i] == matric[j,i+1]) {
        k <- k+1
      biglist[[j]]$other <- k
      k <- i+k
      }
    )
  }


}
```

Matric is the data.frame. biglist is an empty list with 21980 elements and each element is a list with four names= "stability", "anarchy", "change" and "other".

Thanks.[image]

Also, I should mention that I found a way to get the repeats for each value in a row, easily, with the function rle().
Nonetheless, this does not work since at the end of the day what I really need is numbers, corresponding to the length of repeat for each value ("anarchy", "change", etc) for each row, to be able to average them further.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example/expected output

Comment: Hi Akrun, what kind of example could I provide? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution where we pull the data into long form, then do grouping and counting to summarize the contiguous repeated values.

```
library(tidyverse)
# using sample data from below

df %>%
  # convert to long form to help with grouping & counting
  gather(col, val, -OBJECTID) %>%
  arrange(OBJECTID, col) %>%

  # for each OBJECTID row...
  group_by(OBJECTID) %>%
  # Assign a group to each contiguous set of vals by making
  #   a new group whenever val doesn't match the prior one
  mutate(new_grp = val != lag(val, default = ""),
         grp = cumsum(new_grp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # Count how many in each group & word within each row
  count(OBJECTID, val, grp) %>%
  # Count how many groups of each length by word & row
  count(OBJECTID, val, n) %>%
  rename(grp_length = n,
         count      = nn)
# A tibble: 103,432 x 4
   OBJECTID val       grp_length count
      <int> <chr>          <int> <int>
 1        1 anarchy            1     1
 2        1 change             1     1
 3        1 change             2     1
 4        1 other              1     1
 5        1 stability          1     1
 6        1 stability          3     1
 7        2 anarchy            1     1
 8        2 anarchy            2     1
 9        2 change             1     1
10        2 change             2     1
# … with 103,422 more rows
```

This means that OBJECTID 1 has one "anarchy" string of length 1, one "change" string of length 1 and one of length 2, one "other" string of length 1, one "stability" string of length one and one of length 3.

---

Sample data:

```
df_rows <- 21980
df_columns <- 9
set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(
        OBJECTID = rep(1:df_rows, each = df_columns),
        col = rep(paste0("c", 1:df_columns), times = df_rows),
        val = sample(c("other", "anarchy", "stability", "change"), 
      size = df_rows * df_columns, replace = TRUE)
      ) %>% spread(col, val)

> df
# A tibble: 21,980 x 10
   OBJECTID c1        c2        c3        c4        c5        c6        c7        c8        c9       
      <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
 1        1 change    change    anarchy   change    stability stability stability other     stability
 2        2 stability anarchy   stability change    anarchy   anarchy   change    change    other    
 3        3 anarchy   stability change    other     change    change    other     stability anarchy  
 4        4 change    anarchy   change    stability change    anarchy   stability other     change   
 5        5 other     other     change    stability anarchy   anarchy   other     change    anarchy  
 6        6 change    change    stability change    stability anarchy   anarchy   anarchy   change   
 7        7 other     stability stability other     anarchy   stability stability change    change   
 8        8 stability change    other     anarchy   change    stability other     other     other    
 9        9 other     anarchy   other     stability other     anarchy   stability other     stability
10       10 other     anarchy   stability change    stability other     other     other     anarchy 
# … with 21,970 more rows
```

Comment: Dear Jon, infinitely many thanks from the east shore of the Bay Area!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a dataframe `df` with 9 columns that looks something like this and that I have understood your question correctly

```
str(df)

 $ OBJECTID: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ REP1    : chr  "anarchy" "change" "stability" "other" ...
 $ REP2    : chr  "anarchy" "stability" "anarchy" "change" ...
 $ REP3    : chr  "other" "anarchy" "stability" "anarchy" ...
 $ REP4    : chr  "change" "stability" "change" "anarchy" ...
 $ REP5    : chr  "anarchy" "stability" "stability" "other" ...
 $ REP6    : chr  "other" "anarchy" "stability" "stability" ...
 $ REP7    : chr  "stability" "stability" "anarchy" "stability" ...
 $ REP8    : chr  "change" "anatchy" "change" "chang
```

You can use `tidyr` to reshape it and count the number of occurrences of each government for each `OBJECTID`.

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(rep, gov, 2:9) %>% 
  group_by(OBJECTID, gov) %>% 
  summarize(count = n())
```

you will get something like this

```
OBJECTID  gov       count
1        anarchy    3       
1        change     2       
1        other      2       
1        stability  1       
2        anarchy    3       
2        change     1       
2        stability  4       
3        anatchy    2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, I would like to get for each government the length of the different repetitions. Say, there are two repetitions of anarchy, one of length two and one of length three, how this table will help me see this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The table shows for each ```OBJECTID``` how many times (```count```) each government is present. For example, anarchy was present 3 times in  the first row (```OBJECTID```  1),  change was present 2...

Comment: I think that actually what you want is @JonSpring solution